# why always getting 0 from a json key?

Tags: android, json

[image]

Working on a project where i am performing some operation based on instruction code. there are some json keys. where i am getting all the required values but have problem to get one among all. I am a initial level developer here.
Note : at everytime when i try to get instruction value in my android code i get 0.can anybody suggest me how should i go through now.

You can refer screenshot for my code.

[image]

From server I am getting proper json response.

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "error": "",
    "result": [
        {
            "message": "Network is requesting permission to connect to your phone",
            "instruction": 111,
            "imei_no": "b2b5e4012e3c8b49",
            "socket_user_id": "u566135811c9a2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you please like to share the code, where you are parsing JSON.

Comment: and where is image attached?

Comment: can you see the image?

Comment: instruction is within the first object of the result array. You can't get instruction like the way you have it. 0 is probably the default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the JSON value with not the correct key.

The correct way to get the key value is:

```
int instruction= json.getJSONArray("Result").getJSONObject(0).optInt("instruction")
```

Global version:

```
json.getJSONArray("Result").getJSONObject(index_of_array).optInt("instruction")
```

**public long optLong (String name)**

Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a long or can be coerced to a long, or 0 otherwise. Note that JSON represents numbers as doubles, so this is lossy; use strings to transfer numbers via JSON.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Try this Hope this will Work!

```
 final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
 final JSONArray array= obj.getJSONArray("result");
 final int n = array.length();
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  final JSONObject result= array.getJSONObject(i);
  System.out.println(result.getString("message"));
  System.out.println(result.getString("instruction"));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not retrieving "result" from `json`. You'll need to retrieve result, which should give you an array, and then retrieve the first object of the array, in order to retrieve its property `instruction`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a result of optInt method:

> public int optInt(java.lang.String key)
>
> Get an optional int value associated with a key, **or zero if there is no  such key**
>   or if the value is not a number. If the value is a string, an >attempt will be made to evaluate it as a number.

You should get JsonArray "Result" and next get first JsonObject. Now, you can access to "instruction".